# App Rejection - Kids category

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

My App was just rejected with a reason:

> “You have selected the Kids category for your app, but your app does
>   not appear to be designed specifically for kids aged 11 and under.
>   Specifically, we noticed that your app is a CRM app.”

Actually, no terms or conditions can be found in App Store Review Guidelines that indicate how I can solve this. So funny. I mean, I didn't select "Made for kids" and my app doesn't contain violence, horror, sex… so my app is rated automatically for Ages 4+. ¿?

[image]

**Update**

I uploaded a new binary and added new lines of codes. The app has been approved.

```
if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() == true {
    // Your subscribe code here
}
```

I guess it checks if the user (a kid) could make payments or not because the parental control is activated.

Comment: Contact the review board, not much we can do. Just appeal the review and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! So frustrating

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for Apple support, not a question about programming as defined by the Help Center.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple App Store review guidelines / Apple support / app design instead of directly about programming and coding.

Comment: Appstore approval has 1,1K questions here. Do you really think a developer only has to know about the code? xD

Answer (score 2):

As per rejection reason its not looks like its rejected due to that ratings or selections on above image you said.

Its rejected because might be you have selected Kids or relevant to kids category or subcategory. So that is what it causing the rejection.

So the possible solution is make sure in your application selected category or sub category should not be kids or relevant to kids.

Still if it not works than you can ask for the more clarification under the rejection comment. By this way either they will give clarification or app will directly go into the review status & again & will get approval.

**Note :**

The above solution I have given as per the experience of uploading 150+ apps & resolving 50+ rejection issues.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks Mayur. I thought the same about categories at first. However the category/subcategory is business and productivity.

I wrote a rejection comment. No answer. I uploaded a new binary and it was approved today.

I added:

if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() == true {
}

Comment: @torcelly its great you got the solution eventually. Its a unique issue so +1 for it